# PHP: Regular expression / preg_match() until EOL

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

In an HTML page is a line like this:

```
<p><strong>State:</strong> <a href="/state/show/Ohio">Ohio</a></p>
```

What I'm looking for is a regex which gets the content between `<strong>State:</strong>` and the EOL.

I've tried this but it doesn't work because it ignores the `</a></p>-"end"`

```
preg_match('/<strong>State:(.*)<\/a><\/p>/',$html,$format);
```

Comment: Can you please update your post with the exact output you're expecting with that case?  Do you want <strong>State:</strong> <a href="/state/show/Ohio">Ohio</a></p>?  

If so ... just replace (.*) with .*

Comment: If you want to match until end of line you could use `<strong>State:(.*)`

Comment: any reason for not considering html parsers.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will find the `<p><strong>State:</strong>` and return everything from `</strong>` to the end of the line into group 1. Note by including the `$` symbol you'll also want to include the `m` option to force the regex to allow the `$` to match end of lines.

With your sample text: `<p><strong>State:</strong> <a href="/state/show/Ohio">Ohio</a></p>`

Regex: `<p><strong>State:(</strong>.*?$)`

[image]

Group 1 will have `</strong> <a href="/state/show/Ohio">Ohio</a></p>`

If you really want to just capture the anchor tag directly after the strong tag group not including the close `</p>`, then try this:

Regex: `<p><strong>State:</strong>\s*(.*?)</p>$`

[image]

Group 1 will have `<a href="/state/show/Ohio">Ohio</a>`

## Disclaimer

Parsing HTML with regex may not be the easiest thing to maintain in the long run. However if you have control over your input text, the text remains pretty much uncomplicated, and you're willing to have the periodic edge case where a regular expresion might fail then regex will work for you.

## PHP Html Parse

Enough of the soap box. If you're ready to investigate html parsing in PHP then have a look at this  example of pulling all the anchor tags on a page and returning their href attribute and link text:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.YourPageHere.com/')); 

// echo Links and their anchor text
echo '<pre>';
echo "Link\tAnchor\n";
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $anchor = $link->nodeValue;
    echo $href,"\t",$anchor,"\n";
    }
echo '</pre>';
```